# osmdroid долго грузит карту

Tags: android, openstreetmap

Всем хай! Помогите разобрать с osmdroid, подгрузил либу, захожу в приложение - долго грузит карту, очень долго.. (сожрал интернет трафик более 100мб пока подгружал - это норм?)

вот мой код:

```
    mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
    mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mMapView.setUseDataConnection(true);

    Marker.ENABLE_TEXT_LABELS_WHEN_NO_IMAGE = true;
    Marker m = new Marker(mMapView);

    GeoPoint gPt = new GeoPoint(41.352263, 69.3572467);

    MapController mapController = (MapController) mMapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(15);
    mapController.setCenter(gPt);

    m.setPosition(gPt);
    m.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
    m.setTitle("Мой ребенок\n28.02.2018, 23:00:00, 100%, 45, 333");
    m.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.intouch_icon));
    mMapView.getOverlays().add(m);
```

и еще пару вопросов:

если ли в osmdroid слой "вид со спутника" как в гугле?

можно ли настроить при подгрузки карты определенную страну, чтоб дальше этой страны osm не подгружал? нужно в случае долгой подгрузки карты и расходование трафика - если это решиться, то вопрос отпадает

Comment: добавил разрешение на чтение памяти, в настройках по умолчание было выключено, включил вручную, вроде карта стала норм загружаться - странно почему не спросил разрешение.